# Amazon S3 bucket MalformedXML error when uploading

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a picture to my Amazon S3 bucket. Here is the code for my XMLHttpRequest:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append(filename, file);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com', true);
xhr.send(form_data);
```

I have configured the CORS to be as follows:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error when I attempt to upload to it:

```
PUT https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com 400 (Bad Request)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MalformedXML</Code><Message>The XML you provided was not well-formed or 
did not validate against our published schema</Message><RequestId>6188AA51D1EE6B38</RequestId>
<HostId>f3d5Aj8bMyMOJywRnYKH/tBXRHCDWFvNzcb4ejs9F4/IulP1P2n0XoN1mDq7LpQgL/RIsW1c6RA=</HostId></Error>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you're sending the PUT request to the bucket itself, without an object name. S3 interprets this as a PUT BUCKET request, and expects the body to be a CreateBucketConfiguration XML document.

To upload a file, your XHR open call should look more like:

```
xhr.open('PUT', 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/' + filename, true);
```

There's an example request in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html).

Comment: Good catch.  Problem #2, after that is fixed, is that S3 buckets don't expect "form data" on a `PUT` request.  They expect the request body to contain the raw octets of the object being uploaded.

Comment: I've mostly been working with the Javascript API rather than directly sending REST requests. Not sure what your form data looks like, but the example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html might move you in the right direction?

Comment: Happend to me to with the Java SDK. I was not sending the bucket name.